# parsing a file so as to get the top 10 players.

Tags: python, list, parsing

I have a very large text file that contains hockey statistics.

I need two things from each line:

1. the name of the player
2. the points.(the first set of numbers)

And I want to return the top 10 list.

Below is a sample of the text file but it continues much longer.

```
html_log:Bob 1217.1 1.75 696:48 1 5 38 6 109 61 14:42 633 223 25 435:36 182 34 0.55    
html_log:Steve 485.5 1.26 385:18 7 12 -1 28 172 218 16:04 839 94 101 143:18 44 15 -0.03
html_log:Jim 1153.3 1.84 625:54 1 2 71 3 2 10 7:58 499 3 5 616:36 241 36 1.13
```

-repeats with more players and stats (no newlines)

I need to get the player name,  in this case the text following the "html_log" tag
I also need the first set of numbers, and need to output to return a top 10 list.

Optimum result would output

->>

```
Bob 1217.1
Jim 1153.3
Steve 485.5
```

+
rest of users in text file and their rating, highest to lowest.
or just the top 10 highest out of the text file.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What part are you stuck on? Parsing the file should be easy with either a couple of `split` calls or a regex. Getting the top 10 from any iterable is easy with `heapq.nlargest`. If you design your code right, that iterable can be an iterator that you feed as you go along.

Comment: How large is large? Kilobytes, megabytes, gigabytes?

Comment: i agree with @abarnert. parsing this file is quite easy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just break it down into small pieces, each of which is easy.

In English: For each line in the file, you want the first two values, and you want to split the first value after the colon, and you want to treat the second value as a number. Then, you want to keep track of the top 10 pairs, ordered by that second value.

In Python:

```
with open('large_file.txt') as f:
    pairs = (line.split()[:2] for line in f)
    processed_pairs = ((pair[0].split(':')[1], float(pair[1])) for pair in pairs)
    top_10_pairs = heapq.nlargest(10, processed_pairs, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Now you've got a `list` of `name`, `score` pairs, which is easy to print out:

```
for name, score in top_10_pairs:
    print('{} {}'.format(name, score))
```

No matter how big the file is, this won't keep more than 10 processed pairs (plus a read buffer and some other basic stuff) in memory at a time, because we're just transforming an iterator full of files (a file) step by step into other iterators, and feeding that into `heapq.nlargest`, which only keeps the top `n` around.

Answer (score 2):

```
dict(line.split()[:2] for line in
    [line.split(":")[1] for line in data.split("\n")])
#  {'Bob': '1217.1', 'Jim': '1153.3', 'Steve': '485.5'}
```

Comment: This doesn't sort the results, or get the top 10. While you can add a `sorted(d.items(), key=lambda pair: float(pair[1]), reversed=True)` or something, that's going to require keeping (two copies of) the whole thing into memory, and doing an O(N log N) sort, neither of which are necessary here.

Answer (score -3):

The following code does exactly what you wanted to do:

filin = open('file','r')

```
d = {}

for i in filin:

    startName = i.find('html_log:') + len('html_log:')

    endName = i.find(' ',startName)

    name = i[startName:endName]

    startPoint = endName + 1

    endPoint = i.find(' ',startPoint)

    points = i[startPoint:endPoint]

    d[points] = name

d.keys().sort()

counter = 0  ##to make sure that we print only the top 10

filin.close()

for key in d.keys():


    print d[key],' ',key

    counter += 1

    if counter == 10:

        break
```

Comment: If the lines don't all start with `html_log:`, this will do the wrong thing (and if they _do_ all start with `html_log:`, it's unnecessary). And I'd give 50/50 odds that you've got at least one off-by-one error in there somewhere, too. That's exactly why we have functions like `split`, so we don't have to deal with that stuff.

Comment: Also, you're sorting by the string value of `points`, so `9` is going to count as higher than `1000`. And you need to have enough memory to read the entire file into memory this way even though you only want the top 10. And you never close the file. And using a manually-incremented `counter` in a loop is silly; just use `enumerate`. But why even bother when you can just slice it?

Comment: @abarnert: this seemed a very intuitive way to do it. And file parsing should be more about parsing the file in hand rather than using all kinds of functions! Though I agree with you on the string comparison thing! my bad!

Comment: If you want to do everything by hand C-style instead of using functions that are built in to Python, why are you even using Python?

Comment: @abarnert: well I don't really know! Anyway, can you tell me how I can handle that string comparison thing??

Comment: Just use `split` and/or `partition`. For example, to get everything after a `html_log:` if present, nothing if it's not present, that's just `line.partition('html_log:')[-1]`. To get the first two columns in a space-separated line, that's just `line.split()[:2]`. And so on.